# Solve equation on mathematical physics

Tags: mathematical-physics

Show that
$$\gamma_+ - \gamma_-=\frac{2\beta_0\beta}{\sqrt{(1-\beta_0^2)(1-\beta^2)}}$$
where
$$\gamma_+=(1-\beta^2_+)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \ \mbox{and} \ \beta_+=\frac{\beta_0+\beta}{1+\beta_0\beta}$$
$$\gamma_-=(1-\beta^2_-)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \ \mbox{and} \ \beta_-=\frac{\beta_0-\beta}{1-\beta_0\beta}$$

Comment: I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: do you know anything about the sign of $\beta$'s?

Comment: No, I don't know.

Comment: Ok then, I will assum that $\beta\beta_0>0$.  I think you can try  moving the the $\gamma_-$ term to the other side of the equation and squaring both sides afterwards

Comment: You just need to substitute the definition of $\beta_{\pm}$ into definition of $\gamma_{\pm}$ and uses the identities: $(1\pm\beta\beta_0)^2 - (\beta\pm\beta_0)^2 = (1-\beta^2)(1-\beta_0^2)$.

Comment: What are you think about my answer?

Comment: Your answer is on the wrong track. you should show $\gamma_{\pm} = \frac{1\pm\beta_0\beta}{\sqrt{(1-\beta^2)(1-\beta_0^2)}}$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

I was moved $\gamma_-$ to other side equation:
$$\gamma_+=\frac{2\beta_0\beta}{\sqrt{(1-\beta_0^2)(1-\beta^2)}}+\gamma_-$$
So
$$\gamma_+=\frac{2\beta_0\beta}{\sqrt{(1-\beta_0^2)(1-\beta^2)}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2_-}}$$
Therefore
$$\gamma_-=\frac{2\beta_0\beta\sqrt{1-\beta^2}+\sqrt{(1-\beta^2_0)(1-\beta^2)}}{\sqrt{(1-\beta_0^2)(1-\beta^2)}\sqrt{1-\beta^2_-}}$$
So we come to the conclusion that
$$\gamma_-^2=\left(\frac{2\beta_0\beta\sqrt{1-\beta^2}+\sqrt{(1-\beta^2_0)(1-\beta^2)}}{\sqrt{(1-\beta_0^2)(1-\beta^2)}\sqrt{1-\beta^2_-}}\right)^2$$
$$\gamma_-^2=\frac{\left(2\beta_0\beta\sqrt{1-\beta^2}+\sqrt{(1-\beta^2_0)(1-\beta^2)}\right)^2}{\left(\sqrt{(1-\beta_0^2)(1-\beta^2)}\sqrt{1-\beta^2_-}\right)^2}$$
Well I think?